# $\forall A\exists L(\mathcal P(L)=A)$

Tags: set-theory, foundations

To be honest this idea is not mine but i saw this axiom somewhere and I dont remember where

Is the axiom that say that exist the "logarithm set" $L$ for every set $A$.

> "$\forall A\exists L(\mathcal P(L)=A)$"

Using the intuition in tha naive set theory we can see that such $L$ ca not exist always and we can derive some contradiction too (in the naive concept) like for example this

we have that

$\forall X (\varnothing \subset X)$ then $\forall X (\varnothing \in \mathcal P(X))$

But if we allow the logarithm set axiom we have

$\forall A\exists L(\mathcal P(L)=A)$ imply $\forall A(\varnothing \in A)$
and is not true.

In addition we have that the logarithm set $L$ of $A$ always belongs to $A$.

$\forall A (\varnothing \in A)$

If I understand well this means that the logarithm aximom is useless beacuse states the existence of an element $L$ of the set $A$ for every set $A$, then is in contraddiction with the empty set axiom.

At this point I must ask why and when this axiom can be used:

> 1- Do the contraddictions that I've found are enough for "kicking out
> of the game" this axiom for ever?
>
> 2-There can be an alternative
> collection of set theory axiom that can allow this axiom to be
> interesting? Maybe we can extend the universe of the set with "exotic"
> sets that make us always able to  take the "Logarith set" of every
> set?

Sorry if I made some grammar errors and thanks in advance.

Comment: A cute question which I know absolutely nothing about how to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the contradiction that you have found is sufficient to conclude that this axiom is *very* contradictory (i.e. it is a contradiction to one of the fundamental properties of set theory, namely the empty set).

One can perhaps modify this to be an argument of cardinality. That is, $$\forall A\exists L(A\neq\varnothing\rightarrow|2^L|=|A|),$$ but that is also not going to work. Note that the integers are **not** closed under taking $\log_2$. If you want this axiom to make sense somehow then you need to circumvent this fact. There will never be any set whose power set contains exactly three elements.

So maybe if we require that $A$ is infinite? But that also going to fail. $\aleph_0$ has the property that $|2^X|\neq\aleph_0$, no matter what $X$ is. And it is not the only infinite cardinal that has this property. So you're going to try and work harder and harder on that. This will also negate the existence of inaccessible cardinals, which have the same property as $\aleph_0$ here.

So let's assume that we want to maximize the class of sets equipotent with power sets. What do I mean by maximize? Well given an infinite cardinal $\aleph_\alpha$, I want that the cardinals smaller than $\aleph_\alpha$ which are equipotent with power sets is as large as possible without causing contradictions for smaller $\alpha$'s. Assume that we can formalize this, let us observe the consequence and then see what is the correct formalization.

So we know what happens with finite sets, and we know that not all infinite sets can be equipotent with power sets. $\aleph_0$ can't be. But $\aleph_1$ can be. In that case $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$. Then we want $\aleph_2$ to be a power set, and so $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$. We can continue. It is not hard to see that by the time we reached $\aleph_\omega$, the first limit cardinal, $\sf GCH$ holds below it. We have to skip $\aleph_\omega$ because it provably can't be equipotent to a power set. So we continue in a similar fashion, and it is apparent that by the time we reached $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ that the power sets of sets of smaller cardinality are exactly $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$.

While $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is eligible as a power set (e.g. it is consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is $\aleph_{\omega_1}$), since we already have that it is a strong limit cardinal -- it can't a power set. We can continue on and on, so we have that in fact $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for every ordinal $\alpha$.

Essentially, we require $\sf GCH$ to hold. That we can formalize.

Comment: Although you might want to mention that switching the quantifiers somewhat $\forall L \exists A ( \mathcal P(L) = A )$ is a way of stating the power set axiom.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks, but I suppose that this was the origin of the question "what happens when we reverse the power set axiom?"

Comment: (Irrelevant, but of course, rather than sets being equal, the last paragraph really means equipotent.) More relevant: "Whenever it is consistent that a set equals a power set" How does one formalize this?

Comment: @Andres: We know what are the conditions for a finite set to be equipotent to a power set; for infinite cardinals it has to be that they are not strongly inaccessible cardinals, and they do not have countable cofinality. However now we are at an impasse, because if all the uncountable regular cardinals below $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ are equipotent to power sets, then $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ itself is not a power set of any set. So we need to exclude it as well. By the same argument all the other limit cardinals have to be excluded. If so, this is just a backwards way of stating $\sf GCH$.

Comment: (This comment only applies to the previous version of the answer.) The statement you wrote is too informal and needs more care, is all I'm saying. For example: It is consistent that $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is a power set, after all. (The current version addresses this.)

Comment: mmh, that is more than I expected, I need time to read it and understand. Anyway you hitted the core sayng that the integers are not closend under the $\log_2$ function, in fact I was thinking about sets with non integer cardinality, or set not in bijection with finite ordinals. But is more difficult to understand than I excepted.

Comment: @MphLee: Suppose that you had a set of cardinality $\log_23$, $X$. Then its power set had three elements. But the cardinality of a set is less than that of its power set, so $X$ has to have $0,1$ or $2$ elements. No power set of those has $3$ elements. Contradiction. Of course you can require more, or less, from sets, but then why call them "sets"?

Comment: Just a comment about the need to exclude $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ if we've arranged for all smaller cardinals to be cardinalities of power sets whenever possible. Actually, of course, $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is excluded much sooner. A specific formulation is that each of $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ can consistently be the cardinality of a power set, but they can't both be.  Similarly, any two of $\aleph_1$, $\aleph_2$, and $\aleph_{\omega_2}$ can be cardinalities of power sets, but not all three.

Comment: @Andreas: That sounds reasonable. Although I can't see immediately why $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ (or some other limit ordinal) can't be $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ while being a strong limit.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The cofinality of $2^\kappa$ is always $>\kappa$. So the only $\kappa$ for which $2^\kappa=\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is consistent is $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @Andreas: D'oh. Obviously. I, for some strange reason, had in mind $\operatorname{cf}(2^{\kappa})>\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$. It's a good thing that I almost finished grading homework assignments from the semester... they really seem to rot my brain.

Comment: @AsafKaragila so we can maybe define a new theory with the something that beahave as the zfc sets, and other objects that make us able to have something like "negative or rational cardinalities" but at the end probably we are not working on sets anymore right?

Comment: @MphLee: See [this answer of mine on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136366/has-negative-cardinality-been-considered/136388#136388). The thing about "negative cardinality" is that if you want cardinality arithmetics and $|A|=-1$ then $|A|+|A\times A|=0$. But this means that something which is more or less the union of two non-empty "sets" is empty, and that makes no sense. So the arithmetics that we know goes out the window. If so, what is cardinality, and what exactly does it measure?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't know what is exatly cardinality, but I always believed that in the real world we do arithmetic with cardinals often. And the definitions of cardinality given in the foundations of mathematics like the usual with bijections and ordinals or the equivalence classes of all sets of cardinality $n$ are in my opinion only approximations to the concept of cardinality: like Peano's axiom try to catch the essence of the numbers, cardinality tries the same with the concept of quantity. Anyways I found very interesting stuff in your link, thanks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In the end, the reason of my question was if this axiom or something similar was able to imply the existence of exotic objects in the univers of sets, objects that need a new concept of cardinality because are not reallt sets.